# How to drop rows based on datetime (every 15 min)?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

This is an example of a larger dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"DateTime":["2020-04-02 06:06:22","2020-04-02 06:12:22","2020-04-02 06:35:34","2020-04-02 07:06:09",
                               "2020-04-02 07:10:34","2020-04-02 07:41:44"],
                   "Data":[23, 31, 10, 23, 56, 81]})

# column DateTime type must be datetime64[ns]
df["DateTime"] = df["DateTime"].astype("datetime64[ns]")

df
Out[8]: 
             DateTime  Data
0 2020-04-02 06:06:22    23
1 2020-04-02 06:12:22    31
2 2020-04-02 06:35:34    10
3 2020-04-02 07:06:09    23
4 2020-04-02 07:10:34    56
5 2020-04-02 07:41:44    81
```

I would like to drop a row if the date in df["DateTime"] in the row below occurs faster than 15 minutes when compared to the actual row. And the result should be like this:

```
              DateTime  Data
0 2020-04-02 06:06:22    23
2 2020-04-02 06:35:34    10
3 2020-04-02 07:06:09    23
5 2020-04-02 07:41:44    81
```

Does anyone know any condition I could use to set these intervals (every 15 min) and drop these rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) to generate a `Timedelta`:

```
m = df['DateTime'].diff().lt('15min')

out = df[~m]
```

Output:

```
             DateTime  Data
0 2020-04-02 06:06:22    23
2 2020-04-02 06:35:34    10
3 2020-04-02 07:06:09    23
5 2020-04-02 07:41:44    81
```

Intermediate `~m`:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
Name: DateTime, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Timedelta` column:

```
df['diff'] = df['DateTime'] - df['DateTime'].shift(1)
```

Drop if the `Timedelta` column is less than 15 minutes.

```
>>> df[df['diff'].fillna(pd.Timedelta.max) > '15 minutes']
             DateTime  Data            diff
0 2020-04-02 06:06:22    23             NaT
2 2020-04-02 06:35:34    10 0 days 00:23:12
3 2020-04-02 07:06:09    23 0 days 00:30:35
5 2020-04-02 07:41:44    81 0 days 00:31:10
```